Missing 'winningPlan' while using 'explain()' with query in MongoDB
I've configured a search index on my collection and implemented the following queries:
Query 1:
db.productDimensions.explain().aggregate([{
    $search: {
      "text": {
        "path": "name",
        "query": "productName"
      }
    }
  },
  {$sort: { name: 1 }}
]);

Query 2:
db.productDimensions.explain("executionStats").aggregate([{
  "$search": {
    "text": {
      "path": "name",
      "query": "productName"
    },
    "sort": {
      unused: {$meta: "searchScore"},
      "name": 1,
    }
  }
}]);

Upon executing these queries with explain(), I observed that the winningPlan field was absent. How can I verify whether the search index is being utilized? My understanding is that the winningPlan typically indicates whether the index is utilized. If this assumption is incorrect, how can I determine if the search index is indeed being used?

$search is an Atlas-specific aggregation pipeline stage. It is not a core MongoDB function but rather a binding to ElasticSearch sidecar.
If $seach is a first stage in the pipeline, Atlas converts it to an ES query, retrieves the data and passes it to the next stage.
It is not subject for query planner, as the $search index is not a native MongoDb index, and the index is always being used as long as $search stage is included in the pipeline.
